# jquery radio button validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a single search option field for searching in different ways by clicking the radio buttons given on that page. For example search by search-client-by-id, search-client-by-name, search-client-by-emailid etc. and I want to put different jQuery validations on it on the same search field by clicking on different radio buttons.

The validations used for this purpose are like this demo:
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

```
<div class="search-job-txtbox" >
      <input type="text" name="clientSearchText" id="clientSearchText" value="" class="search-txtbox" onkeyup="javascript:searchByCriteria(this.value,'radio');"/>
      <div class="search-icon"><a href="javascript:;"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/search-icon.gif" width="25" alt="Search" title="Search" height="25" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-options">
      <div class="job-checkbox"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="search-client-by-id" checked="true" onclick="javascript:searchByCriteria();"/></div>
    <h5>ID</h5>
    <div class="job-checkbox"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="search-client-by-name" /></div>
    <h5>Name</h5>
    <div class="job-checkbox"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="search-client-by-emailid" /></div>
    <h5>Email</h5>
     <div class="job-checkbox"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="search-client-by-contact-number" /></div>
    <h5>Contact</h5>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the validation dynamically

```
$('input.clientID').click(function() {
   $('#form').validationEngine(options);
});
```

Do that for each type, or implement a case/switch

Comment: can you please suggest me some example...?